Upper expectation bound for generalized multiplication
Let $\{X_k\}_{k=1}^N$ be a sequence of positive independent random variables such that $\mathbb{E}[X_k] \leq 1$.
Let $\phi:(0,\infty) \to J$ such that:

$\phi$ strictly increasing and concave.
$\phi(1) = 0$.
$\lim_{x\to 0} \phi(x) = -\infty$

Now define the pseudo multiplication $x \circ y = \phi^{-1}(\phi(x) + \phi(y))$, wherever the operation is well-defined. As an example:
$$x \circ y = (x^\gamma + y^\gamma -1)^\frac{1}{\gamma},$$
with $\phi(x) = \frac{x^\gamma-1}{\gamma}$.
Also define $\bigcirc_{k=1}^N y_k = y_1 \circ y_2 \circ \dots \circ y_N = \phi^{-1}(\sum_k \phi(y_k))$.
My question is:
For independent random variables, $\mathbb{E}[\prod_k X_k] = \prod_k\mathbb{E}[X_k]\leq 1$. In this case, $\prod_k$ corresponds to $x\circ y$ with $\phi(x)=\log(x)$.
What conditions do I need to have $\mathbb{E}[\bigcirc_{k=1}^N X_k] \leq 1$?

What I have so far:

Define the generalized means:
$$\mathcal{M}_\phi(x;w) = \phi^{-1}\left(\sum_k w_k \phi(x_k)\right),\quad \forall (x,w)\in \mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n: w^T\mathbf{1} =1.$$

Then we have the comparison:
$$\mathcal{M}_\phi(x;w) \leq \mathcal{M}_\psi(x;w) \iff \psi(\phi^{-1}(x))\text{ is convex}.$$
Taking $\psi(x) = x$ we have that $\mathcal{M}_\phi\left(x;\frac{\mathbf{1}}{n}\right) \leq \frac{1}{n}\sum_k x_k$.
Now, it suffices to have $v_\phi(y)=\phi^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{n}\phi(y)\right)$ concave to arrive at the desired inequality.
Are there simple conditions on $\phi$ that make $v_\phi$ concave?
